# How to use Splitter layout in a one of the views to show master/detail data

Tags: sapui5

Our app is a sap.m.App(). App starts and user has 3 main buttons to click to see 3 different views. He wants one of those views to be split layout which will show master/detail data instead of them being separate pages like so far.

Is this possible, or doses entire app has to be in split mode?

Can I even use xml views that already exist to insert them into splitter or do I have to create entire content of the splitter in the splitter view context?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sap.m.SplitContainer` [[1]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitContainer.html) to create a Split Layout inside your App without changing other views.